# Getting URL of UIWebView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm sort of new to Xcode, so forgive me in advance for any obvious wrong things that I might write.

I'm trying to write something a bit simple using the UIWebView.  I've already made it load upon the app's loading, but I can't seem to do anything else.  What I want to do next is to make a button appear/disappear depending on the current URL.  This is what I used to (try to) get the current URL:

```
NSString *currentURL = viewWeb.request.URL.absoluteString;
```

(I'm using this code in the `ViewController.h` file)

When I made the outlet (Ctrl+dragging), I named it `viewWeb` and I also went and labeled it `viewWeb`.  But it doesn't seem to work and I don't know why.

Also, please don't just give me some code without explaining, because this is a bit frustrating and I want to understand it.

EDIT: Thanks, but I'm not looking for help on the disappearing button just yet (by the way, `viewWeb` is my UIWebView, not the button).  I need help to detect an URL change to make the button disappear.  Is there a `webViewDidLoad` or something similar? `viewDidLoad` isn't for this.

Answer (score 1):

In the ViewController.h File, you only declare the property, like this:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *currentURL;
```

Then you can set the value in the ViewController.m file.

maybe in the `-viewDidLoad` method in the ViewController.m file like this:

```
_currentURL = viewWeb.request.URL.absoluteString;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property of hidden or not of the button to show it selectively based on the url.

```
// URLString contains the URL based on which you would like to show/hide the button
if ([currentURL isEqualToString:URLString]) {
    viewWeb.hidden = NO;
}
else {
    viewWeb.hidden = YES;
}
```